# AIX : Create core dump or running process on without terminating it

Tags: solaris, aix

Have known about using the command `gcore` on Solaris.
Is there something similar for `AIX` ?

I have a `Siebel component` running on an `AIX` server and it flunks without anything in the logs.
I know when it is in a panic state, hence want to `make it core dump` before it dies completely.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have [`gencore`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/gencore.htm)?

Comment: Thanks ! Seems it'll do it without terminating the program !

Comment: is there something like Gencore for Oracle's JDK?

Comment: @djangofan: You might want to ask that question on Stack Overflow.